# Django urls.py only one app

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I just started playing with Django, I love it! I followed the tutorial from the Django documentation, but have the following question:

I only have one app (polls), currently I always have localhost/polls/{urlname}

Is there a way to remove the polls keyword? So people that go to localhost automatically go to my app polls? At the moment, I have this wildcard

```
url(r'.*$', RedirectView.as_view(url='polls/', permanent=False), name='index'),
```

But this still keeps polls in the url. This is my complete urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'.*$', RedirectView.as_view(url='polls/', permanent=False), name='index'),
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `polls/` prefix in the regex of the "include" url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Quite easy, those regular expressions are still a bit confusing for beginners. Thanks for the patience;)